# Can the integrated Sachs-Wolfe and the Rees-Sciama effects have any influence on matter?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, gravity, astrophysics, space-expansion

CMB photons can be affected by the expansion of the universe through the linear integrated Sachs-Wolfe effect (ISW) [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachs%E2%80%93Wolfe_effect) and the non-linear ISW effect or also called Rees-Sciama effect [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachs%E2%80%93Wolfe_effect).

In particular, according to the ISW effect, the photons crossing superclusters would leave them having a total net blueshift (because of the gravitational potential decay of the cluster) while crossing a supervoid would leave them with a total net redshift (all compared to the overall redshift from the universe's expansion itself)

The Rees-Sciama effect on the other hand, "cools" a bit the photons crossing both structures but "heats" them to those that travel near the outskirts of both superclusters and supervoids [2](https://www.roe.ac.uk/%7Ecai/index_ISW.html)

However, we are always talking about photons here. Do these effects also affect matter (or particles with mass) in any manner? For instance, since gravitational potentials are related to these effects, shouldn't that have some kind of influence for particles with mass as well (and not only masless particles, like photons)? Can these effects affect the orbits of celestial bodies in clusters and voids, for instance?

Comment: I don't see the point of your question. ISW is just what you get when you integrate along a photon's worldline in a perturbed FRW universe. For instance, if we can measure cosmic neutrino background very precisely, similar effects on those massive neutrinos will be taken into consideration.